# Perhaps explicit type conversion produces C++ compile error

Tags: c++

I don't know the real problem in this case but I guess here is the problem with type conversion (as I can see here is an explicit type conversion or an implicit type conversion).

Here is the code sample that produces compile error.

```
class Vector
{
public:
   Vector(double x, double y) : x_(x), y_(y){}

private:
   double x_, y_;
};        

class Operation
{
public:
   class ConcreteOp
   {
   public:
      ConcreteOp(const Vector& v) : v_(v){}

   private:
      Vector v_;
   };

   Operation(const ConcreteOp& op) : op_(op){}

private:
   ConcreteOp op_;   
};        

class Method
{
public:
   Method(const Operation& op) : op_(op){}

private:
   Operation op_;
};        

void test(const Method& m)
{
}

int main()
{
   Vector v(2, 2);
   Method m( Operation( Operation::ConcreteOp(v) ) );    

   test(m);
   return 0;
}
```

the compile error looks like:

```
 invalid initialization of reference of type «const Method&» from expression of type «Method(Operation (*)(Operation::ConcreteOp))»
    test(m);
         ^
```

In my working project the compile error begins a bit of differently:

```
 no matching function for call to «Program::Ship::testMethod(Program::Object::Transformation::Method (&)(Program::TransformOperation))»
      testMethod(m);
                  ^
```

At the same time the following code is compiled with no problems:

```
int main()
{
   Vector v(2, 2);
   Method m( Operation( Operation::ConcreteOp(Vector(2, 2) /* v*/ ) ) );

   test(m);
   return 0;
}
```

Also two brackets solve the problem:

```
int main()
{
   Vector v(2, 2);
   Method m( (Operation( Operation::ConcreteOp(/*Vector(2, 2)*/ v ) ) ) );
   //        ^                                                        ^ 

   test(m);
   return 0;
}
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Method m( Operation( Operation::ConcreteOp(v) ) );
```

This declares a function named `m`, returning `Method` and taking a function as a parameter; it does not declare a variable named `m`. Use braces, like this:

```
Method m { Operation( Operation::ConcreteOp(v) ) };
```

See also: [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

Comment: I wonder if it is time that ["most vexing parse"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22most+vexing+parse%22+site%3Astackoverflow.com&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-US:IE-Address&ie=&oe=&gws_rd=ssl) gets its own tag?  And, speaking as a C++-phile, it's a darn shame that other languages don't have something similar we could throw back at them ...